# Is there a linear explosion capability in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Current explosion functionality seems to be radial, which is great for turbines etc, but not so good for shaft based assemblies (Like a bolt, washer and nut combo, for example).

Is there code available to enable a linear explosion - i.e. along a specified axis? And if not, how would be go about creating a custom explode feature that would facilitate that?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The explode process is a sequence of displacements, you can change it to only one axis. The following articles may help:

- [View each floor, using 'Vertical explode'](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/view-each-floor-using-vertical-explode)
- [Selective explode in the viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selective-explode-viewer)